# Backwards time dilation paradox

Tags: interstellar-travel, physics, time, relativistic-rocket

We have a pair of atomic clocks. Let's call them clock A and clock B. We switch both of them on at the same time. Clock A will stay on Earth and clock B will go with the astronauts.

Astronauts with the clock B will accelerate in direction away from the Sun for 10 years (from the astronauts' perspective) at 1 g. Than they will start braking process that will take 1 year at 10 g.
After the braking process is finished, the astronauts are not moving away from Earth anymore. They turn around and head back to Earth.
The travel back will be according to the same scenario. 10 years of acceleration at 1 g and braking 1 year at 10 g.

And the astronauts are (back) home on earth.

The time on clock B is 22 years. What time is on clock A?

....now in opposite scenario (1 year of acceleration with 10 g and 10 year of braking with 1 g) the astronauts will travel to future as the clock B shows 22 while clock A 372...but can someone describe how what I have mentioned works?

Comment: Or is the result on A again 372years?

Comment: In scenarios when we change intensity of breaking to intensity of acceleration no other condition changes. We have traveled the same road, in the same time...using the same amount of energy (from the astronauts perspective)...we only differently distribute the energy. So if the outcome of above example is different than A is 372 years could it mean there is dirrect connection between energy distribution and time?

Comment: This is better suited for Physics.SE.

Comment: hmmm perhaps to truly describe how I mean it I would need third timeline of some third object that again move towards earth and astronauts....I feel what I wrote is incoimplete. If I will find better way to formulate it i will

Comment: Unfortunatelly physics.se requires loging

Comment: you're already a member here, you can join Physics using the same account.

Comment: @MiroslavŘešetka as I mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33590/time-dilation-between-mars-and-earth-due-to-different-mass#comment104398_33592) you may find answers in *existing questions and answer* there. Before posting there, you should probably take some time reading all of the great answers that have been written already.

Comment: Thanks again. I mean I would read it before I posted...if I have had know this...thnks for the tip.

Comment: My advice: Learn about and understand the twin paradox. Newbies to relativity theory tend to want to make things even more complex (as is the case with this question). Triplets paradox, acceleration, uneven acceleration: These things hinder rather than aid understanding. There are a number of basic-level questions and answers on the twin paradox on Physics.se.